# can use service inside a foreach()

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-observables, vis.js

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewComponent } from '../view/view.component';
import { HitoService } from '../../services/hito.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-time-line',
  templateUrl: './time-line.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./time-line.component.css'],
  providers: [HitoService]
})

export class TimeLineComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  @Input() calbuscador: String;
  @Input() idcalbuscador: String;
  public pepe: String
  nom_cal1: any;
  hito1: any = {};
  hito2: any = {};

  constructor(public _hitoService: HitoService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ///we retrieve the value sento to this component in OnChanges
  ngOnChanges() {

    this.nom_cal1 = this.calbuscador;
    this.drawtimeline(this.nom_cal1, this._hitoService, this.idcalbuscador);
  }

  result: any[] = [];
  drawtimeline(nom_cal, _hitoService, idcalbuscador) {

    var container = document.getElementById('timeLine');
    //alert("id cal sele es :" + idcalbuscador);

    var k = 0;
    var j = 0;

    var master = new vis.DataSet();
    var items = new vis.DataSet();

    this.result.push({  "_id": this.idcalbuscador,
      "title": nom_cal });

    this.result.forEach(function (ev) {
      master.add([{ id: ev._id, content: ev.title, cal_id: ev._id }]);
      var g = ev._id;

      for (var i= 0; i<this.result.length; i++){
        console.log("hola");
        console.log(this.result[i]._id);
        this._hitoService.getHitos(this.result[i]._id)
              .subscribe(hito2 => {
                this.hito2 = hito2
                var items: any;
                items = hito2;

          items.forEach(function (item) {
            items.add([{ id: k, group: g, start: item.start_datetime, end: item.end_datetime, style: itemStyle(item.design), className: "pepe" }]);
            k++;
          });
          j++;
        }); 
      }
    });
```

I am trying to implement a timeline using the vis.js, I retrieve the name and id of the timeline want in this class component then in the `ngOnChanges` I call the function to draw the timeline passing to it the name of the timeline, it's id and the services in other to get the observables item of the this specific timeline. I have an array that will store the timelines (result) I want to view and then an observable I subscribed to, to add the items of the timelines. The first `foreach()` will remove the first element in the result array, get the observables of items for that result and the second `foreach()` will go through the observables items and print the items, then it start over and move to the next. But all I get in the browsers console is : `TypeError: this is undefined`. Probably not making use of the service in the `forach()`

Comment: You need to create an arrow function `() => {}` to bind `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an arrow function inside your forEach to keep using the enclosing scope.

```js
this.result.forEach((ev) => {
  // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign current `this` to another variable (Say, `that`) then, use `that` into your callback.

**Note:** Inside your callback function `this` is changed to the JavaScript context by which the function is called.

```
const that = this;        // save the current 'this' to 'that' variable

this.result.forEach(function (ev) {
      master.add([{ id: ev._id, content: ev.title, cal_id: ev._id }]);
      var g = ev._id;

      for (var i= 0; i< that.result.length; i++){
        console.log("hola");
        console.log(that.result[i]._id);
        that._hitoService.getHitos(that.result[i]._id)
              .subscribe(hito2 => {
                that.hito2 = hito2
                var items: any;
                items = hito2;

                ....
             ....
           ....
```